# Using Arrays.asList with int array

Tags: java, arrays, list, collections

Using `java.util.Arrays.asList`, why its shows different list size  for `int` (Primitive type) and `String` array?

a) With `int` array, whenever I execute following program the List size = 1

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int ar[]=new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
        List list=Arrays.asList(ar);
        System.out.println(list.size());

    }
```

b) But if i change from `int` array type to `String` array(like `String ar[] = new String[]{"abc","klm","xyz","pqr"};`) , then I am getting the list size as 4 which i think is correct.

**PS** : With `Integer` (Wrapper Class) array, then result is Fine, but i am not sure why in primitive `int` array, the list size is 1. Please explain.

Comment: Probably your compiler even gave you a raw type warning on `List`. Many IDEs will present a couple of useful fixes, one of them changing `List` to `List<int[]>`. The latter pointing you towards the answers of "daerin" and "icza".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`List` cannot hold primitive values because of java generics (see [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18021218/create-a-list-of-primitive-int)). So when you call `Arrays.asList(ar)` the Arrays creates a list with exactly one item - the int array `ar`.

EDIT:

Result of `Arrays.asList(ar)` will be a `List<int[]>`, **NOT** `List<int>` and it will hold one item which is the array of `int`s:

```
[ [1,2,3,4,5] ]
```

You cannot access the primitive `int`s from the list itself. You would have to access it like this:

```
list.get(0).get(0) // returns 1
list.get(0).get(1) // returns 2
...
```

And I think that's not what you wanted.

Comment: So If the Arrays creates a list with exactly one item -the int array `ar` then how to traverse and access that primitive values from it using list?

Comment: Got it! It should be like `int ab[]=(int[]) list.get(0);`

Comment: Watch carefully! `list.get(0).get(0)` wouldn't be accessible directly here as last `get()` is undefined until and unless you **typecast** the whole statement to some other collection (that have `get` method)

Answer (score 1):

`List` is a generic type, primitive types are not valid substitutes for the type parameter.

So in your first example when you call `Arrays.asList()` with an `int[]`, the value for the type parameter will be `int[]` and not `int`, and it will return a list of int arrays. It will have only 1 element, the array itself.

The second case will be a `List<String>`, properly holding the 4 strings which you pass to it.