# How can I do what I think this code is doing without getting a ClassCastException?

Tags: java, classcastexception

I have read other similar questions on StackOverflow but do not understand the root cause, and can't figure out a fix on my own. Could you help me understand what the issue is?

Here is my code:

```
List<List<Integer>> res;

public List<List<Integer>> permute(int[] nums) {
    res = new ArrayList();
    List<Integer> n = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(nums));
    permute(n, new ArrayList());
    return res;
}

private void permute(List<Integer> nums, List<Integer> cur) {
    if (nums.size() == 0) {
        res.add(cur);
        return;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i) {
        List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>(cur);
        List<Integer> temp2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(nums);
        Integer c = (Integer)nums.get(i); (line 20)
        temp2.remove(i);
        
        permute(temp2, temp);
    }
}
```

but I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class [I cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer ([I and java.lang.Integer are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
  at line 20, Solution.permute
  at line 7, Solution.permute
  at line 54, __DriverSolution__.__helper__
  at line 84, __Driver__.main
```

Comment: What's inside `nums`? Where's the code that puts stuff in it?

Comment: Why are you casting this?

Comment: @m.antkowicz sorry, that was after playing around trying to get it to work, I forgot to remove it. Keeping it now for the sake of anyone reading this, so they don't get confused.

Comment: This code doesn't do anything. The for loop is removing values from a copy of the original List, not the List.  You don't need the cast.  Depending on the size of the Lists, you're gobbling up a ton of memory.

Comment: @Ryan I'm just playing around with this, I understand it might not be optimal. Please help me understand the issue on line 20.

Comment: @web1connoisseur `List<Integer> n = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(nums));` didn't this throw a warning?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca it did not. However, I'm doing this in LeetCode's web IDE.

Comment: `([I and java.lang.Integer are ...`,  this `I`, where it comes from ? Strange error message ...

Comment: @web1connoisseur I see. By the way my point is, `n` is not what you think it is, since `new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(nums))` does *not* return a `List<Integer>`. So when you cast the result of `get`ting something from it you're not `get`ing an `Integer` and the cast fails.

Comment: See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2607327/133203) as for what is happening here (and the other answers in that thread to see how to circumvent this).

Comment: Typecast error can be removed if you know how to circumvent the integer type.

Comment: Regarding your question: "_this `I`, where it comes from?_" - the identifier is actually `[I`. For an explanation see [\[L array notation - where does it come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5085889/12567365) In your case, it refers to an array of integers. @PeterMmm

Comment: `Integer c` is never being used ...so what's the point?

Comment: @MartinZeitler this solution isn't finished past where the error occurs. I would have added c to temp before calling permute.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Arrays.asList with int array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25483854/using-arrays-aslist-with-int-array) (not the best duplicate but it explains what the end result is and my ddg-fu is failing me)

Comment: As noted in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607289/converting-array-to-list-in-java/30281879#comment123882111_30281879), these days you can use `List<Integer> n = Arrays.stream(nums).boxed().toList();` to avoid this problem. See also Josh Bloch's _Effective Java_ (3rd Edition) item 32: "Combine generics and varargs judiciously".

Comment: That worked, thanks @andrewJames! If you want to post that as the answer, I'll accept it

Comment: I don't think I can write an answer for this, as it would be a duplicate of the question [Converting array to list in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2607289/12567365).  The explanation of the problem is referenced in [this answer about generics and varargs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2607327/12567365) in that question. And one solution is referenced in [this other answer which uses the stream and `boxed()` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30281879/12567365) in the same question. I would go vote for those, instead of voting for any answer here.

Comment: You could also use `Integer[]` instead of `int[]`.