# Unexpected type TreeSet Java

Tags: java, treeset

In this line

```
public TreeSet<int> storage = new TreeSet<int>();
```

I get the following error when I try to compile:

> error: unexpected type
>
> ```
> public TreeSet<int> storage = new TreeSet<int>();
> ```

What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: You can only declare reference types as the arguments for generic type parameters. `int` is not a reference type.

Comment: Think you have to Change from int to Integer

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18021218/create-a-list-of-primitive-int

Answer (score 0):

Generics enable types (classes and interfaces) to be parameters when defining classes, interfaces and methods. So, parameters SHOULD not be primitive.

Change it to,

```
TreeSet <Integer> storage = new TreeSet<>();
             (or)
Set <Integer> storage = new TreeSet<>();
```