# Best data structure to hold large amounts of data?

Tags: java, data-structures

Reading in a lot of data from a file. There may be 100 different data objects with necessary headings, but there can be well over 300,000 values stored in each of these data objects. The values need to be stored in the same order that they are read in. This is the constructor for the data object:

```
public Data(String heading, ArrayList<Float> values) {
    this.heading = heading;
    this.values = values;
}
```

What would be the quickest way to store and retrieve these values sequentially  in RAM?

Comment: Well, since the order is important, you'll use the Data Structures implementing the `Queue` interface. Such as `LinkedList`

Comment: What's wrong with ArrayList? Do you need random-access to these elements?

Comment: What do you mean by "most efficient"? Taking up the least memory? Fastest to write? Fastest to read sequentially? Fastest to retrieve (by what criteria?) ? What have you tried so far, and why do you think it's not "efficient" enough?

Comment: ... amending the question to answer the questions above might be enough to reverse the close votes.

Comment: @cricket_007 I do not like using an arraylist as it allocates a lot more memory than is needed.

Comment: @slim by most efficient way I mean the quickest, sorry for the lack of information. I have tried arraylist but while debugging I notice it allocated a lot more memory than is needed.

Comment: You just contradicted yourself. First you said you want 'quickest' (quickest at what?), then you said the problem was high memory use. What do you actually need? 30 million doubles is inherently 240MB. You're effectively doubling that by using `java.lang.Double`, but even so...

Comment: PS, rather than adding info in the comments, edit the actual question to explain what you mean.

Comment: Quickest to access how? Sequentially? Randomly? By key? If `ArrayList` takes too much space, then load the data into a temporary `ArrayList` and call `ToArray` on it to get an array that contains exactly the number of items you need, and dispose of the `ArrayList`. You really need to edit your question to add more information: how the data will be accessed, and what your performance requirements are (memory and CPU resources).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although in your comments you mention "quickness", without specifying what operation needs to be "quick", your main concern seems to be heap memory consumption.

Let's assume 100 groups of 300,000 numbers (you've used words like "may be" and "well over" but this will do as an example).

That's 30,000,000 numbers to store, plus 100 headings and some structural overhead for grouping.

A primitive Java `float` is 32 bits, that is 4 bytes. So at an absolute minimum, you're going to need 30,000,000 * 4 bytes == 120MB.

An array of primitives - `float[30000000]` - is just all the values concatenated into a contiguous chunk of memory, so will consume this theoretical minumum of 120MB -- plus a few bytes of once-per-array overhead that I won't go into detail about here.

A java `Float` wrapper object is 12 bytes. When you store an object (rather than a primitive) in an array, the reference itself is 4 bytes. So an array of `Float` - `Float[30000000]` will consume 30,000,000 * (12 + 4) == 480MB.

So, you can cut your memory use by more than half by using primitives rather than wrappers.

---

An `ArrayList` is quite a light wrapper around an array of `Object` and so has about the same memory costs. The once-per-list overheads are too small to have an impact compared to the elements, at these list sizes. But there are some caveats:

- `ArrayList` can only store Objects, not primitives, so if you choose a `List` you're stuck with the 12-bytes-per-element overhead of `Float`.

  - There are some third-party libraries that provide lists of primitives - see: [Create a List of primitive int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18021218/create-a-list-of-primitive-int)
- The capacity of an `ArrayList` is dynamic, and to achieve this, if you grow the list to be bigger than its backing array, it will:

  - create a new array, 50% bigger than the old array
  - copy the contents of the old array into the new array (this sounds expensive, but hardware is very fast at doing this)
  - discard the old array
  - This means that if the backing array happens to have 30 million elements, and is full, `ArrayList.add()` will replace the array with one of 45 million elements, even if your `List` only needs 30,000,001.
  - You can avoid this if you know the needed capacity in advance, by providing the capacity in the constructor.
  - You can use `ArrayList.trimToSize()` to drop unneeded capacity and claw some memory back after you've filled the `ArrayList`.

---

If I was striving to use as little heap memory as possible, I would aim to store my lists of numbers as arrays of primitives:

```
 class Data {
     String header;
     float[] values;
 }
```

... and I would just put these into an `ArrayList<Data>`.

With this structure, you have O(1) access to arbitrary values, and you can use `Arrays.binarySearch()` (if the values are sorted) to find by value within a group.

If at all possible, I would find out the size of each group before reading the values, and initialise the array to the right size. If you can, make your input file format facilitate this:

```
 while(line = readLine()) {
     if(isHeader(line)) {
          ParsedHeader header = new ParsedHeader(line);
          currentArray = new float[header.size()];
          arrayIndex = 0;
          currentGroup = new Group(header.name(), currentArray);

          groups.add(currentGroup);
     } else if (isValue(line)) {
          currentArray[arrayIndex++] = parseValue(line);
     }
 }
```

If you can't change the input format, consider making two passes through the file - once to discover group lengths, once again to fill your arrays.

If you *have to* consume the file in one pass, and the file format can't provide group lengths before groups, then you'll have to do something that allows a "list" to grow arbitrarily. There are several options:

- Consume each group into an `ArrayList<Float>` - when the group is complete, convert it into an `array[float]`:

  ```
  float[] array = new float[list.size()];
  int i = 0;
  for (Float f : list) {
      array[i] = f; // auto-unboxes Float to float
  }
  ```
- Use a third-party list-of-float library class
- Copy the logic used by ArrayList to replace your array with a bigger one when needed -- http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.ensureCapacity%28int%29
- Any number of approaches discussed in Computer Science textbooks, for example a linked list of arrays.

---

**However** none of this considers your reasons for slurping all these numbers into memory in the first place, nor whether this store meets your needs when it comes to processing the numbers.

You should step back and consider what your actual data processing requirement is, and whether slurping into memory is the best approach.

See whether you can do your processing by storing only a slice of data at a time, rather than storing the whole thing in memory. For example, to calculate max/min/mean, you don't need every number to be in memory -- you just need to keep a running total.

Or, consider using a lightweight database library.

Answer (score -2):

You could use a [RedBlack BST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree), which will be an extremely efficient way to store/retrieve data. This relies on nodes that link to other nodes, so there's no limit to the size of the input, as long as you have enough memory for java.