# Find maximal elements in array and delete all lines and columns that contain it

Tags: java

if we have these numbers in

```
array [][]
{1, 2, 3, 4},
{1, 2, 20, 4},
{1, 20, 2, 4},
{1, 2, 3, 4},};
```

it should looks like this

```
1 0 0 4 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 4
```

but i could output code only like this...

```
1 0 3 4 
1 0 20 4 
0 0 0 0 
1 0 3 4
```

and i don't understand how to correct it, please help me,
this is my code.Thanks!

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] array2 = {{1, 2, 3, 4},
                {1, 2, 20, 4},
                {1, 20, 2, 4},
                {1, 2, 3, 4},};

        int countMax = 0;
        int countIndexHorizontal = 0;
        int countIndexVertical = 0;
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int m, k,x;

        for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array2[i].length; j++) {
                if (array2[i][j] > max) {
                    max = array2[i][j];   
                }
            }
        }

        for (k = 0; k < array2.length; k++) {
            for (m = 0; m < array2[k].length; m++) {
                if (array2[k][m] == max) {
                    countIndexHorizontal = k;
                    countIndexVertical = m;
                    for (x = 0; x < array2.length; x++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < array2[x].length; j++) {
                            if (countIndexVertical == x || j == countIndexHorizontal) {
                                array2[x][j] = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array2[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(array2[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

it looks like there are a lot of code and a little of words and site don't allow me to finally post my question and i'm really angry, maybe this text will help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Why should it look like 'this'?

Comment: because programe should find maximal values and delete all lines and column that consist maximal values

Comment: Instead of *consist* you wanted to say *contain*? If we understand your input as a matrix, the highest value is `20`, hence all rows and columns containing `20` must have their values set at `0`.

Comment: Please also give the task **inside the question** instead of only in the title. As you see it confuses people otherwise.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to say contain. Sorry, English isn't my tongue language. Ok, next time I'll do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Algorithm

This is the part when you only use pen and paper. Basically, I understood the problem as follow:

> Given a matrix with *n* rows and *m* columns of [`Integer`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer)<sup>1</sup>:
>
> 1. Find the highest value
> 2. All entries in the rows and columns holding the highest value must have its value set at 0
> 3. Print the updated matrix

### Assumption

I made the following assumptions:

1. In *n* is not necessarily equal to *m*. For example, you can have the array:

   ```
   Valid Input
   1  2  3  4  5  6
   7  8  9 10 11 12
   7  8 12  5  6  4
   ```

   which must give, as 12 is the highest value:

   ```
   Output
   1  2  0  4  5  0
   0  0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0  0  0
   ```
2. The matrix is consistent: every row has *m* columns and every column has *n* rows. For example, such input is incorrect:

   ```
   Incorrect input
   1  2  3
   7  8  9 10
   7  8
   ```

### Logic

*At this stage, you're still using pen, paper and Google only!*

In my problem understanding, I splitted in three parts as I thought this is how you understood the problem. This is the *mathematics* understanding. Now let's convert it into a more *Java* understanding. First of all, we need to translate some vocabulary:

```
Mathematics wording |     Java wording
--------------------|---------------------
      matrix        |  2-dimensional array
      Integer       |  int (primitive type)
```

which gives in Java way:

> Given an 2-dimensional `int[][]` array:
>
> 1. **Find the highest value**
> 2. **Find the row*s* and column*s*** holding the highest value
> 3. **Update the array** by setting the value to 0 for the row*s* and column*s* found in 2.
> 4. **Print the array**

In the specific case of my solution, I combine *1. + 2.* and I combined *3. + 4.*

## What you did

Let's open your favorite IDE and compare my analysis with your input:

1. **Find the highest value: OK here**: : you use the variable `max` and scan the matrix to find the maximum value. You also assumed that the matrix could be rectangle (*n* rows and *m* columns with *n != m*). So it's good

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < array2[i].length; j++) {
           if (array2[i][j] > max) {
               max = array2[i][j];
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. **Find the row*s* and column*s***: **ERROR here**, as mentioned by [ccp-beginner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6253321/cpp-beginner), when you found a the highest value, you *erase* (set to zero) the value for the whole column and whole row but maybe the same highest value was stored somewhere else in this row or column

   ```
   for (k = 0; k < array2.length; k++) {
       for (m = 0; m < array2[k].length; m++) {
           if (array2[k][m] == max) {
               countIndexHorizontal = k;
               countIndexVertical = m;
               // additional operation defined in 3.
           }

           // in ccp-beginner example of
           //  2, 2
           //  1, 1
           // if k=0 and m=0, you'll update the value
           // of the first row and first column giving:
           //  0, 0
           //  0, 1
           // but when k=0, m=1, you'll find 0 instead 
           // of 2 so your program will consider that
           // this row / column does not contain the 
           // highest value
       }
   }
   ```

   I assume here the

   - countIndexHorizontal = row
   - countIndexVertical = column

   So you need to keep track of the row*s* and column*s* when you're setting the values to 0.
3. **Update the array**: **ERROR here** (cf [ccp-beginner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6253321/cpp-beginner)'s answer)

   ```
               for (x = 0; x < array2.length; x++) {
                   for (int j = 0; j < array2[x].length; j++) {
                       if (countIndexVertical == x || j == countIndexHorizontal) {
                           array2[x][j] = 0;

                           // In your example:
                           // 1  2  3  4
                           // 1  2 20  4
                           // 1 20  2  4
                           // 1  2  3  4
                           // and if countIndexVertical=2 and countIndexHorizontal=1 
                           // (the 20 of the second row between 2 and 4), you'll have
                           // 1  0  3  4
                           // 1  0 20  4
                           // 0  0  0  0
                           // 1  0  3  4
                           // instead of
                           // 1  2  0  4
                           // 0  0  0  0
                           // 1 20  0  4
                           // 1  2  0  4
                       }
                   }
               }
   ```

   you got confused between `countIndexVertical` and `countIndexHorizontal`, as you have

   - x = row
   - j = column

   You should had (please notice the swapping)

   ```
                   if (countIndexHorizontal == x || j == countIndexVertical) {
                       array2[x][j] = 0;
                   }
   ```
4. **Print the array: OK here**, nothing special to mention

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < array2[i].length; j++) {
           System.out.print(array2[i][j] + " ");
       }
       System.out.println();
   }
   ```

### The problem

Basically, what you need is how to store the rows and the columns containing the highest value. At first, we could be tempted to use array again right, like

```
int[] rowsContainingHighestValue;
int[] columnsContainingHighestValue;
```

But you don't know how many highest value you'll encounter so you need something to store multiple value with a dynamic size: I'll use `List`.

### Some Java point

The `rowsContainingHighestValue` and `columnsContainingHighestValue` become:

```
List<Integer> rowsContainingHighestValue = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> columnsContainingHighestValue = new ArrayList<>();
```

You may want to have a look at the following point:

1. Why [`List` instead of `array`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589813/when-to-use-a-list-over-an-array-in-java)?
2. My objects are declared as `List` but I **instantiate**<sup>2</sup> with `ArrayList`: [What is  a `Interface` and what is a `Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html)
3. Why I used [`List<Integer>` instead of `List<int>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18021218/create-a-list-of-primitive-int)
4. What is [the difference between `Integer` and `int`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660691/what-is-the-difference-between-integer-and-int-in-java)

## One solution

1. loop through for the matrix to fetch the maximum value and store **all** rows and columns holding this value instead of a single row/column combination (`countIndexHorizontal` and `countIndexVertical`)

   1. If a new maximum value is found, store it (like you did) *AND* store the current row and column index
   2. If a value is identical to the current maximum value (e.g. you have `20` twice), then **append** the row and column index to the existing respective row / column list
2. loop a second time for updating and printing the value

   1. it's basically combining your two last double-loop: if the scanned element belongs to a row **or** a column holding the maximum value, then the value must be set at 0 (exactly the way you did but shorter as I already have the list of rows / columns)
   2. once the values are properly updated, just proceed to a simple printing

Which in code gives:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] array2 = {
        {1, 2, 3, 4},
        {1, 2, 20, 4},
        {1, 20, 2, 4},
        {1, 2, 3, 4}
    };

    // find the maximum value and store its position:
    // It's List instead of a single value as multiple 
    // rows and columns can hold the same maximum value
    List<Integer> rowsWithMaxValue = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> colsWithMaxValue = new ArrayList<>();
    int maxValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    // First matrix-scan to fetch the maximum value and the
    // row(s) and column(s) to set the value at 0
    for (int row = 0; row < array2.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < array2[row].length; col++) {

            // get the current value
            int value = array2[row][col];

            // found a new maximum or an existing one?
            if (value > maxValue) {
                // this is a new maximum value, we can reset
                // the list as the previous rows and columns
                // are not relevant anymore
                maxValue = value;
                rowsWithMaxValue = new ArrayList<>();
                colsWithMaxValue = new ArrayList<>();
                rowsWithMaxValue.add(row);
                colsWithMaxValue.add(col);
            } else if (value == maxValue) {
                // The same value (like 20) is found again
                // so multiple rows and columns will have 
                // their value set at 0
                rowsWithMaxValue.add(row);
                colsWithMaxValue.add(col);
            }
        }
    }

    // Second matrix-scan for updating the values and printing
    for (int row = 0; row < array2.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < array2[row].length; col++) {
            // is it in a forbidden row? If yes, set the value
            // at zero. One of the condition (row or column) is
            // enough to have its value set at 0
            if (rowsWithMaxValue.contains(row) || colsWithMaxValue.contains(col)) {
                array2[row][col] = 0;
            }
            
            // Simply print the value
            System.out.print(array2[row][col] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Integer in the mathematics meaning: positive or negative number without decimal</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>I won't explain instantiation here. Feel free to google it</sub>

Comment: I'm learning Java only for a month and i don't know and understand a lot of that you've written  :<

Comment: @AndrewStill, I've updated my answer and I consider it pretty exhaustive. I hope it is understandable to you. Please keep in my mind that I won't replace any teaching otherwise it would be *10$ + one beer per hour*. I'm joking but you get the idea. Happy reading and happy coding! If my answer helped you, please accept / upvote it

Comment: It was really understandable and pretty exhaustive! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcomed and glad it helped. Feel free to up vote cpp's answer if it was useful to you (you can accept one answer but upvote multiple answers)

Comment: I haven't enough reputation (

Comment: Oops I forgot that. Sorry >_<

Answer (score 0):

You can improve the program by changing the condition to

```
if (countIndexHorizontal == x || j == countIndexVertical)
```

Your program is deleting the wrong lines for the first 20 it finds (including the other 20).

This change will get you the correct answer for your specific case, but the program is still broken for examples like this

```
2  2
1  1
```

The correct output is

```
0  0
0  0
```

but it won't work because when it finds the first 2 it will delete the second 2, but the second 2 is still needed to clear the 0 in the bottom right corner. You're going to have to keep a separate data structure for the positions you want to clear. I'll leave that for you to figure out.

Comment: but i've already have condition like that you've written or i don't understand  what you mean, please text more information about it,thanks!

Comment: Your condition is "like" that, but you've got the variables the wrong way around

Comment: No! You can find the line which is almost the same as that and see the difference

Comment: No problem. As I said in my answer, it still needs a bit of work, but you're almost there.

Comment: could you drive me to the solution?) where is the problem in code?