# I need to create an array list from a list of 1000 numbers on a txt file. Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, file, arraylist

The Numbers are **not** on the same line, there are 1000 lines each with a number.

This is the code I have but I receive an error when I run it, it points to the int part of the array list and says unexpected type.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Homework4
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {
      //Variables 
      int num;
      int temp; 

      Scanner kb = new Scanner(new File("number.txt"));
      ArrayList<int> list = new ArrayList<int>();
      while (kb.hasNextLine())
      {
         list.add(kb.nextLine());


      }      

      //Close File
      inputFile.close();




   }
}
```

Comment: I don’t know mich about Java, but I think that kb.nextLine() gives you a string. So basically you are adding string to int arraylist. Try casting readLine to int.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the wrapper class `Integer`.

Change `ArrayList<int>` to `ArrayList<Integer>`

Similarly,

```
long-> Long
double-> Double
char-> Character
float-> Float
```

you can read more about primitive type collections [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721546/why-dont-java-generics-support-primitive-types) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18021218/create-a-list-of-primitive-int)

Also, when you read the data from file, using `kb.nextLine()` it returns String type. You can convert it to `Integer` type using `Integer.parseInt()` in the following way.

```
list.add( Integer.parstInt( kb.nextLine() ) );
```

The next part is, closing the resource. 
you have not declared a variable by name `inputFile`. it must be `kb` instead.

```
kb.close();
```

The complete code is as follows

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(new File("number.txt"));
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while (kb.hasNextLine()) {
        list.add(Integer.parseInt(kb.nextLine()));
    }
    kb.close();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This answer is clear and really helps @Myles to understand where the problem is. I can see you just edited, maybe you can also add the Java 8 version of this so it is not inly useful but also up to date.

Answer (score 1):

Since you claim to be reading from a text file, you can use class `java.nio.file.Files` to read it and then use java's [stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) to map each line of the text file to an `Integer` and collect all those `Integer`s to a `java.util.List`, as shown in the following code:

```java
Path path = Paths.get("path-to-your-file");
try {
    List<Integer> integers = Files.lines(path) // throws java.io.IOException
                                  .map(Integer::parseInt)
                                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(integers);
}
catch (IOException x) {
    x.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This is only valid since Java 8, I strongly recommend you to start using it.

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors in that code. Firstly, use `Integer` object wrapper for `int` primitive type. Next, you need to parse the read `String` to integer type with the `Integer.parseInt()` method. And close the `Scanner` instance instead of undefined file variable.
Try following code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Homework4{

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    //Variables
    int num;
    int temp;

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(new File("number.txt"));
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while (kb.hasNextLine())
    {
        list.add(Integer.parseInt(kb.nextLine()));


    }

    //Close File
    kb.close();




}
```

}