# Why trying to covert an int array to List using Arrays.asList gives wrong value?

Tags: java

So I am trying to convert an (primitive) int array to a List,

```
            for(int i=0;i<limit;i++) {
                arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
            }
            List list=Arrays.asList(arr);
            System.out.print(list);
```

Doing this so prints values like this for example, `[[I@59a6e353]` . There is an option to add `<Integer>` before variable list but since the array is primitive int, it could not.
Is there any solution for this? Adding `<int[]>` before variable list isn't an option as I need to call a bounded wildcard method.

Comment: don't print the list, print the content of the list. Lists don't have an implementation for toString, so your result is to be expected

Comment: Use `System.out.print(Arrays.toString(list))`

Comment: @Stultuske printing the contents of the list gives the same result too.

Comment: @Rakkun in that case, how did you try to print the content?

Comment: @Stultuske    for(Object i:list) {
    System.out.println(i);
   }

Comment: `<int[]> List<int[]> java.util.Arrays.asList(int[]... a)` you convert the array to a list of `int[]`

Comment: @JhanzaibHumayun tried that but the ide warns like, The method toString(long[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (List), even though there is a same method for object[] too.

Comment: @Rakkun that's because you force it to use the toString implementation of the Object class, why so surprised it uses the toString implementation of the Object class?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer that is an option but I need to call a (bounded) wildcard method, which I cant call if I try to add <int[]>

Comment: The issue is that you have an array of primitive type `int`. `Arrays.asList()` can't convert it to a `List<Integer>` (`List<int>` is not valid). You need to either have an `Integer[]` array or use another method to convert `int[]` to `List<Integer>`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer yea, that solved my question.

Comment: if you already have an `int[]` array: `List<Integer> list = IntStream.of(array).boxed().toList()` - BTW it is recommended not to use raw types! [JLS 4.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8-400): "*The use of raw types is allowed only as a concession to compatibility of legacy code. The use of raw types in code written after the introduction of generics into the Java programming language is strongly discouraged. It is possible that future versions of the Java programming language will disallow the use of raw types.*"

Comment: @user16320675 yes, seems like Java really discourages the use of raw primitive types in generics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Arrays.asList(arr)` does not creates a `List<Integer>` but a `List<int[]>` with a single element (your `arr`).
You have to declare your variable as `Integer[] arr` if you have to use 'Arrays.asList'.

Answer (score 0):

The signature of method `Arrays.asList` is the following one:

`public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a);`

You can see that it needs an array of generics `T` in input.

Therefore you can pass an array of `Integer` and it works. Example:

```java
List<Integer> list= Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {1,2,3,4});
System.out.print(list);
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

If you pass `int[]` you can have just a `List<int[]>` because `int` is a primitive type and it cannot be used as generic. Example:

```java
List<int[]> list= Arrays.asList(new int[] {1,2,3,4});
System.out.print(list);
```

Output:

```
[[I@6b1274d2]
```

I suggest you to read the answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18021218/create-a-list-of-primitive-int).